# Does an operator exist for this?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So, operators overloading is a great feature of C++, obviously.

But say I wanted to get a member of a class just type using the name of the variable.

So like:

```
class ShortProperty
{
public:
    ShortProperty(short value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
public:
    short operator=(short value)
    {
        this->value = value;
        return value;
    }
private:
    short value;
}

void foo()
{
    ShortProperty myproperty(2);

    // Now I can easily do...
    mtproperty = 3;

    // But say I wanted to do...
    short val = myproperty; // THIS LINE
}
```

Is that possible? Is there a way that will work and by using the variable name, get the member "value"?

Thanks!

Comment: Review twice what you're posting here, to be sure not telling nonsense!

Comment: Contemplated editing that. Decided to sit back and see who bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You do that by providing a conversion operator as a member function.

```
operator short () const
{
   return value;
}
```